# Why is my web service returning error 401 when using Windows Authentication?

Tags: windows, web-services, iis, active-directory, config

I'm setting up a web service that is only supposed to work for users in a certain Active Directory. Unfortunately I'm encountering error 401 - Unauthorized.

**Things I've tried:**

1. I initially tried configuring IIS and the web.config file to grant access to the users in the Active Directory but I couldn't get this to work.
2. Next I decided to take a step back and configure IIS and the web.config file to grant access to *all* users. This too, surprisingly, does not work.

**What happens when I call the web service:**

When I call the web service I immediately get the error message "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."
I didn't get a pop up asking for any credentials, so let me know if that's an issue.

**Relevant Settings in IIS:**

- Anonymous Authentication is Disabled
- Windows Authentication is Enabled
- Authorization Rules is set up to Allow All Users

--

Here are the relevant lines of code in my web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
...
    <security>
        <authorization>
            <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
            <add accessType="Allow" users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

You can see from the code that I allow access to all users (users="*"), but this is still giving me the 401 error.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling the web service?

A 401 is actually the normal first step for Windows Authentication. The whole authentication flow is described here: [Windows Authentication HTTP Request Flow in IIS](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mist/2018/02/14/windows-authentication-http-request-flow-in-iis/).

In short, it responds with a 401 and tells you that it accepts Windows authentication. Then the client (usually a browser) resends the request with the proper authentication. A browser will do this for you.

Since you mention this is a web service, I assume you're handling the request yourself. So the answer about how to solve this depends on how you are making the call to your web service. But there is usually a way to specifically tell it to send Windows credentials (either on the first try, or automatically after the 401 challenge).

Comment: In my case, a Virtual Directory had to be setup with a different user.  This is In "Advanced Settings -> Physical Path Credentials -> ...".